# Find shared type among set of values

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

Given a passed-in `IEnumerable`, is there any built-in method to return a best-matching base type for all the items in the `IEnumerable`, that handles nullable/non-nullable types and inheritance?

Something like this:

```
var hs = new HashSet<object> {1,2,3,null};
Type t = GetSharedType(hs); //returns typeof(int?)

hs = new HashSet<object> {new BaseClass(), new DerivedClass()};
t = GetSharedType(hs); //returns typeof(BaseClass)

hs = new HashSet<object> {"1", 1};
t = GetSharedType(hs); //returns typeof(object) or null
```

(I am aware that I can write my own; my question is if there is something built-in).

Comment: Maybe you should instead refactor your code. Why do you store objects in the same collection which type you don't know?

Comment: @TimSchmelter It's not my collection. (Specifically, it's the ItemsSource for a DataGrid for which I want to build a `Predicate` at runtime, in a generic fashion.)

Comment: Obviously, there are a few places in the *compilers* where they have to make a decision about a "best type" given several candidates, but they're usually working with a severely restricted set (e.g. just two or three types) and usually work with the restriction that the return value must be one of the types passed in (and not some e.g. common supertype). I don't think you're working with such restrictions in place.

Comment: @VadimMartynov If you would like to post an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @ZevSpitz I published my answer. It will not work with your first scenario (with `null`) but works on most scenarios.

Comment: @VadimMartynov That's excellent, because I've already written code that handles the `null` case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No, there is no built-in mechanism** to do this. You can combine several [reflection APIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt656691.aspx).

First you can retrieve real types for each object in collection with [GetType()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
IEnumerable<Type> realTypes = hs.Select(o => o.GetType());
```

Now you will have collection of [Type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type(v=vs.110).aspx) class that have [BaseType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.basetype(v=vs.110).aspx) property and [GetInterfaces()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getinterfaces(v=vs.110).aspx) method. Ypu can use [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18375526/5649561) to get all hierarchy for each type:

```
public static IEnumerable<Type> GetParentTypes(this Type type)
{
    // is there any base type?
    if ((type == null) || (type.BaseType == null))
    {
        yield break;
    }

    // return all implemented or inherited interfaces
    foreach (var i in type.GetInterfaces())
    {
        yield return i;
    }

    // return all inherited types
    var currentBaseType = type.BaseType;
    while (currentBaseType != null)
    {
        yield return currentBaseType;
        currentBaseType= currentBaseType.BaseType;
    }
}
```

You can use it to get collection of hierarchies:

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Type>> baseTypes = realTypes.Select(t => t.GetParentTypes());
```

Next step is to merge all this list to have only intersected values. You can do it with [Enumerable.Intersect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136(v=vs.110).aspx) method and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3191824/5649561) code:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> IntersectAllIfEmpty<T>(params IEnumerable<T>[] lists)
{
    IEnumerable<T> results = null;

    lists = lists.Where(l => l.Any()).ToArray();

    if (lists.Length > 0)
    {
        results = lists[0];

        for (int i = 1; i < lists.Length; i++)
            results = results.Intersect(lists[i]);
    }
    else
    {
        results = new T[0];
    }

    return results;
}
```

Finally, we have:

```
IEnumerable<Type> realTypes = hs.Select(o => o.GetType());
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Type>> baseTypes = realTypes.Select(t => t.GetParentTypes());
IEnumerable<Type> inersectedBaseTypes = IntersectAllIfEmpty(baseTypes);
```

Then we can use Type.IsAssignableFrom() method to iterate each type and ensure that one of them is assignable only from themself:

```
Type mostConcreteType = inersectedBaseTypes.Where(t => inersectedBaseTypes.Count(bt => t.IsAssignableFrom(bt)) == 1).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score -1):

**No**, there is no built in type for doing this. As you have identified by yourself that you have to write by your own. Something like

```
public static Type GetEnumerableType<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
{
    return typeof(T);
}
```

Comment: If `T == object`, this will return `object`, even if all the items are `int` or `null`.

Comment: Your example is not relevant to the question; I've edited to clarify.